# react-native mongo db data update buffering

Tags: database, mongodb, react-native, fetch

i'm beginner of react-native and mongo bd.
i make simple music app. i have a problem in data fetching from server.

i update some data in mongodb. so, i want to update these data in my screen immediately.
but, there are some delay to getData from server so updated data are shown a bit later.
how can i fix this problem?? i'm not sure effective approach to get data from server.

this is my code.

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { Feather, EvilIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Context as BoardContext } from '../../context/BoardContext';

const SelectedContentPage = ({ navigation }) => {
const [content] = useState(navigation.getParam('content'));
const boardName = navigation.getParam('boardName');
const [comment, setComment] = useState('');
const { state, createComment, getUser, getCurrentContent, getCurrentBoard } = useContext(BoardContext);
const [currentContent, setCurrentContent] = useState([]);
const [commentNum, setCommentNum] = useState(0);
const [likes, setLikes] = useState(0);
useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
}, []);
useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentContent(state.currentContent);
    setCommentNum(state.currentContent.commentsNum);
    setLikes(state.currentContent.likes);
}, [state]);
const create = async () => {
    if (comment.length == 0){
        console.log('댓글을 작성해주세요');
    }
    let today = new Date();
    const hour = today.getHours() < 10 ? ' 0' + today.getHours() : ' ' + today.getHours();
    const minute = today.getMinutes() < 10 ? ':0' + today.getMinutes() : ':' + today.getMinutes();
    const time = today.getFullYear() + '/' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + today.getDate() + hour + minute;
    await createComment({ userName: state.user.name, comment: comment, time: time, boardName: boardName, contentId: currentContent._id });
    getCurrentContent({name: boardName, id: currentContent._id});
    getCurrentBoard({name: boardName})
    setComment('');
};

return (
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <View style={{marginTop: 10, marginLeft: 10, justifyContent: 'space-between', marginRight: 10, borderBottomWidth:1 }}>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                <Text>{content.userName}</Text>
                <Text>{content.time}</Text>
            </View>
            <View>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 24 }}>{content.title}</Text>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 18}}>{content.content}</Text>
                <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                    <View style={{flexDirection:'row' }}>
                        <EvilIcons style={{fontSize:18}}name="heart" />
                        <Text>{likes}</Text>
                        <EvilIcons style={{fontSize:18}}name="comment" />
                        <Text>{commentNum}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <TouchableOpacity>
                        <EvilIcons style={{fontSize: 18}} name="heart" />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
        <View>
            <FlatList 
                data={currentContent.comments}
                keyExtractor={(comment)=>comment._id}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                    return (
                        <View style={{marginTop: 10, marginLeft: 10, justifyContent: 'space-between', marginRight: 10, borderBottomWidth:1 }}>
                            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                                <Text>{item.userName}</Text>
                                <Text>{item.time}</Text>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                    <Text>{item.comment}</Text>
                                    {item.likes === 0 ? null :
                                        <View style = {{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                            <EvilIcons style={{fontSize:18}}name="heart" /> 
                                            <Text>{item.likes}</Text>
                                        </View>
                                    }
                                </View>
                                <TouchableOpacity>
                                    <Feather EvilIcons name="heart"/>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    )
                }}
            />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.box}>
            <TextInput 
                autoCapitalize="none"
                autoCorrect={false}
                placeholder="댓글"
                onChangeText={setComment}
                value={comment}
                style={{marginLeft: 10}}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => create()}>
                <Feather style={styles.sendStyle} name="wifi"/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        
    </View>
);
};

const styles=StyleSheet.create({
box: {
    width : 380,
    height : 50,
    justifyContent : 'space-between',
    alignItems : 'center',
    backgroundColor:"#dcdce1",
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginHorizontal: 15,
    marginTop: 30,
    marginBottom: 30,
    borderRadius: 10,
},
sendStyle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    marginRight:10
}
});

export default SelectedContentPage;
```

Thanks a lot:)

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly that you want to fetch data from the server without latency? What kind of delay do you expect to have in the end-product?

Comment: Umm.. i mean, if i create new comment, i want to see that comment immediately. but, Auctually, until seeing that new comment results in Screen, i wait about 1~2 seconds(delay).